# How do you get Eclipse warning messages to not disappear instantly?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-warnings

The little yellow warning symbols and underlines in Eclipse don't last very long, do they?

When I get a warning, after I click on the little warning symbol, I have milliseconds to try to read the warning message before it disappears like a very quick and cautious mouse.

Is there a way to change this or does everyone suffer from this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the pop up is there, you can press F2 to make it stay. Or, you can have your cursor in the yellow underlined section and press Ctrl + 1, which will show you the autofix suggestions, as well as give you a chance to see the warning again.

Comment: So cool. Can't believe I've lived with this nonsense for so long when it's such a simple fix. Thanks a bunch, buddy.

Comment: In the eclipse help, look up the hotkeys and print them out for reference. You don't think they'll be useful until you realize how much time you spend messing with the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about yellow exclamation mark warnings. As long as your mouse is on the exclamation mark or the pop-up it doesn't disappear.